# Postgres Full Text Search field addition with Django migration

Tags: python, django, postgresql, full-text-search, schema-migration

I have followed [this tutorial](http://dlo.me/archives/2014/09/01/postgresql-fts/) and added the PostgreSQL FTS capability to one of the tables of my Django (I'm using 1.8.1) project.

Basically, I have an extra `fts_document` field in my table `my_table` of the `my_app` app.

I'd like to keep the databases up-to-date without having to manually copy and paste commands in PostgreSQL shell on each machine.
Unlike the tutorial, I didn't implement the South part, as I got South conflicting with the current implementation and also found out that Django no has a [native way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemigrations) to do these migrations.

I wasn't able to find any example code, so I am stuck and need help.
I don't post an example code cause I followed the exact structure and steps like in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the equivalent of the south migrations using the `RunSQL` operation. Just create an empty migration using `manage.py makemigration <app_label> --empty`, then add it to the `operations` in the new migration file:

```
operations = [
    migrations.RunSQL("CREATE FUNCTION etc.")
]
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) for full details.

Comment: thanks @knbk!
It says *if you are manually creating a column, you should pass in a list containing an AddField operation here so that the autodetector still has an up-to-date state of the model (otherwise, when you next run makemigrations, it won’t see any operation that adds that field and so will try to run it again)*
How do I declare the new column to be `tsvector` type?

p.s. you have a typo, it's `makemigrations`